# Is this notation to denote how an equation has been manipulated to produce a resulting equation standard?

Tags: notation, quantum-mechanics

In the following image I am specifically referring to the step that produces the result Eq. (4.3). Is the notation off to the side $| \;\,\cdot \frac{1}{\psi(x)f(t)}$ in this step standard? (To anyone else who is initially confused like I was, it just means to perform the operation after the vertical bar on the equation before the vertical bar.) If this notation is not standard, what would be the most standard way of conveying this?

[image: Image depicting separation of variables on TDSE to eventually produce TISE]

Comment: Never seen it before.

Comment: In Germany, this is what you learn to write when solving equations in school.